# I respond to notifications, but neglect why I originally came here

Tags: discussion, notifications

Sometimes I come to a Stack Exchange site to ask a question, but instead I see that I have notifications (with a bright red background, it's hard to fail to see it), respond to them, close the browser tab, return to what I'm working on, then realise that I forgot to ask my question!

What can I do about this?

Are there any user interface changes I can make, such as not showing inbox count unless I ask it to do so, or opening new pages in a new tab by default?

Comment: I usually open the link to the thing that pinged me in another tab. I do what I came to do in this tab, and respond to it when I'm done. If the ping is something urgent, you probably had more concerns in mind than asking a question somewhere else.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M do you right-click the link, or have it configured to automatically open in a new tab?

Comment: Right click. It actually has become a habit.

Comment: However hard it may be, try to click the ask question button immediately after logging into the site. Jot down a few words, doesn't need to be a complete sentence, just some words about the question you want to ask, then go to your notifications and open them in new tab and respond to them or whatever, when done write high quality question and submit it. Then wait around a bit to see if anyone comments on your question for more clarification.

Comment: If you Control-Click the notification, that can open it in a new tab without having to right-click, open in new tab.

Comment: @Quill: Or middle-click. Andrew: Best thing to do with multitasking like that is to enforce long thread slices to minimize the ridiculous context switch performance hit (and lossy cache flushing) the brain suffers, and a good way to do that is to act in a queue, ensuring you get each thing done, or at least to the next memory barrier, before starting new items. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Bookmark `/questions/ask`.
2. ???
3. Profit.

Comment: Go directly to Ask. Do not pass the front page, Do not collect 2 inbox messages. :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Precisely. :)

Answer (score 9):

Not sure what you expect Stack Exchange to do.

While browsing, it's your responsibility to remember what sites you visited and what was your intention when browsing them.

If you're having hard time remembering, all modern browsers offer features like bookmarks to help us mark special pages we know we will want to visit again.

We can't expect sites to read our minds and know "hey, you wanted to use this page, right?"

Comment: "Not sure what you expect Stack Exchange to do." Thanks for this feedback. I've added some possibilities to the question in response, in the last sentence.

Comment: Cheers, and in response to your edit the answer is "no" to both, no such option and while you are free to start feature request(s) asking to add them, I don't expect it to be very popular.